# Java - replace strings in parenthesis

Tags: java, regex, string

How can i do this in java :

given a string, for each text in parenthesis, if it contains "blabla" then remove all text in these parenthesis including parenthesis themselves

example :

```
some string (some text) (blabla foo bar) => some string (some text)
some string (some text) (blabla) => some string (some text)
some string (ex ex) => unchanged (because words in parenthesis doesn't contain "blabla")
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below `replaceAll` function.

```
string.replaceAll("\\([^()]*blabla[^()]*\\)", "");
```

**Explanation:**

- `\\(` Matches a literal `(` symbol.
- `[^()]*` Negated character class which matches any character but not of `(` or `)` zero or more times.
- `blabla` Matches the string `blabla`
- `[^()]*` Negated character class which matches any character but not of `(` or `)` zero or more times.
- `\\)` Matches a literal `)` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

```
\\(.*?\\bblabla\\b.*?\\)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.

http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/12

Use `\b` to make sure you replace only `blabla` and not `abcblablaas`

Answer (score 0):

```
 String x = "some string (some text) (blabla)";
    String replace = x.replace("(blabla)", "");
    System.out.println(""+replace);
```